# When to use multiple column families in HBase?

Tags: hbase

I am new to HBase and currently implementing an application using this data store. To be honest I have very bad time using it. However, as a recommendation in HBase docs, it is preferred to use 1-3 column family. Currently I am using only one. Can someone give me an example when to use multiple column families, please mention some use cases and explain what are the benefits of down that.

Thank a lot

Answer (score 2):

In Hbase one region is assiocated with one column family, so a least one HFile in the FS. More column families means more files, and when you'll query a row, the region server will have to grap data in multiple places, and this will slow your system.

Here is my use case: I use only one column family for my real/legacy/usefull data, and an other for my computed/external/cached/stored-outsite/flatted data. This is usefull if you want to delete/refresh/recompute the data in this temporary CF.

Comment: I really did not understood what you mean by " I use only one column family for my real/legacy/usefull data, and an other for my computed/external/cached/stored-outsite/flatted data." can give an example ?

Comment: If you work on table storing movies, you can consider a CF 'data' with columns like "title", "description", "actors", etc, and an other CF 'computed' with "recommandations", "wiki-crawl-data", "imdb-matching"... See the idea?